# Cannot access Menu Bar Items via pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, win32com, pywinauto

I'm automating the following program via Python: (**Surfer**)

http://www.goldensoftware.com/products/surfer

Some portions of it i cannot control using **win32com.client** (the program libraries do not support it). The part i need to get working can be done by using the programs menu bar. It's just 5 clicks i need to get done. So as an alternative i have been trying to use **pywinauto** (my first try with this). But this time i can not get the menu bar items. I tried analyzing the menus via swapy (https://github.com/pywinauto/SWAPY) but the MenuItems field show up empty (as an empty list []).

here is some test code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=2984)  # tried "win32" as backend also

srf = app.window(process=2984)

srf.menu_select("Help")
```

I get the error:

```
"RuntimeError: There is no menu."
```

The menus I am trying to access are within:

- Edit
- Arrange
- Geoprocessing

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It might be connected with [issue #413](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/413), but I didn't take a look yet.

Comment: Thank you Vasily. I read and tried to understand the issue you've shown. It's above my skill set but again i appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to get the menu controlled via pywinauto:

```
app_dialog.child_window(title="Menu Bar").set_focus()
```

From there is was a matter of controlling the keyboard with the SendKeys() module.

It's a workaround but it gets the job done.